# POST-request with curl too long?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, libcurl

I want to send this POST request from a shell-script:

```
start=&limit=&selectNone=true&importId=111&saveCount=&save=some+keywords+%C3%BCbernehmen&list=7947&list=7983&list=7940&list=7976&list=7953&list=7989&list=7948&list=7984&list=7925&list=7961&toggleAllSelect=on&7947-select=true&7947-id=7947&7983-select=true&7983-id=7983&7940-select=true&7940-id=7940&7976-select=true&7976-id=7976
```

Solution that works:

```
POSTString="--form selectNone=true --form save=some+keywords%C3%BCbernehmen --form toggleAllSelect=on"
IMPORT_ID="$(curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form "importfile=@$3" --form importSource=$4 --form format=formatCSV $5do/ImportPersonsFile | grep 'Import-ID' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,10}')"   echo "Import-ID: $IMPORT_ID"

duplicates="$(curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form "importfile=@$3" --form importSource=$4 --form format=formatCSV $5do/ImportPersonsFile | grep 'Davon Dubletten' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,10}<' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,10}')"
if [ "$duplicates" -ne 0 ]; then
ids=($(curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form "importfile=@$3" --form importSource=asds --form format=formatCSV --form importId=$IMPORT_ID --form limit=9999999 $5do/ImportPersonsEditDuplicates | grep '\-id" v' | grep -Eo '>[0-9]{1,10}<' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,10}'))

for id in "${ids[@]}"
do
  POSTString="--form selectNone=true --form save=Als+Dublette+%C3%BCbernehmen --form toggleAllSelect=on --form list=$id --form $id-id=$id --form $id-select=true"
  curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form importId=$IMPORT_ID $POSTString $5do/ImportPersonsEditDuplicates > /dev/null
  curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form importId=$IMPORT_ID $5do/ImportPersonsFinalise > /dev/null
done
else
echo "no duplicates"
curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form importId=$IMPORT_ID $5do/ImportPersonsFinalise > /dev/null
fi
 echo "done"
```

What i want is a solution as follows, where the string is assembled within the for-loop and then only one curl command is used for all iterations. something like this, which did not work unfortunately.

```
$POSTString="--form selectNone=true --form save=some+keywords+%C3%BCbernehmen --form toggleAllSelect=on"
    for id in "${ids[@]}"
do
  POSTString="$POSTString --form list=$id --form $id-id=$id --form $id-select=true"
done
  curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form importId=$IMPORT_ID $POSTString $5do/ImportPersonsEditDuplicates > /dev/null
  curl -s -F username=$1 -F password=$2 --form importId=$IMPORT_ID $5do/ImportPersonsFinalise > /dev/null
```

Comment: See if my answer helps; switching to an array is the right thing to do anyway; based on the question's title I've added info about the max. command-line length; if it doesn't help, update your answer with _what specifically_ doesn't work and _how it fails_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To robustly store a list of arguments in a variable in Bash:

- use an *array*
- double-quote all variable references, both in the array assignment and when referencing the array itself later

```sh
POSTString=( --form selectNone=true --form save=some+keywords+%C3%BCbernehmen --form toggleAllSelect=on )

for id in "${ids[@]}"; do
  POSTString+=( "${POSTString[@]}" --form list="$id" --form "$id-id=$id" --form "$id-select=true" )
done

curl -s -F username="$1" -F password="$2" --form importId="$IMPORT_ID" "${POSTString[@]}" "$5do/ImportPersonsEditDuplicates" > /dev/null
curl -s -F username="$1" -F password="$2" --form importId="$IMPORT_ID" "${POSTString[@]}" "$5do/ImportPersonsFinalise" > /dev/null
```

If this is really a problem with exceeding the max. command-line length, as the title of your question suggests (least likely on Linux, more likely on OS X, even more likely on Cygwin), you'll see an error message such as `Argument list too long`.<sup>[1]</sup>

To get around the limitation, use `curl`'s `-K` (`--config`) option, which instructs `curl` to read its arguments from a specified file, or, if `-` is the option-argument, from stdin <sup>Tip of the hat to [Daniel Stenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg).</sup>

See `man curl` for the specifics; one potential pitfall is that option-arguments that contain embedded spaces must be explicitly quoted.

---

<sup>[1]
`getconf ARG_MAX` will tell you the upper bound of your system's max. command-line length; the actual limit is lower, depending on the size of your environment.

Additionally, some Linux systems have a limit on the *number of arguments* as well as the *length of individual arguments*.</sup>

Comment: And don't put passwords in command lines, because command lines are public: `ps -ef`

Comment: if it truly is a max command line limit he hits, you can work around it by using curl's -K option and have it read arguments on stdin and pass the huge arguments to curl like that ...